# Zipped file isn't unarchiving

Tags: java, bytearrayoutputstream, zipoutputstream

The following code downloads a zip file. Am I doing something wrong here? The zip file downloads but can't unarchive.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = getByteArrOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("report.txt"));
        zos.write(baos.toByteArray());
        zos.closeEntry();
        zos.close();

        this.setBuffer(baos.toByteArray());
        this.setContentType("application/zip");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
this.setContentType("application/octet-stream")
```

instead of

```
this.setContentType("application/zip")
```

it should work.